# Timeout while waiting for command topic consumer to process command while creating ksql stream

Tags: ksqldb

I am new to KSQL. from my node application when I try to create KSQL stream using REST endpoint I get below error.

```
An unexpected error occurred while creating stream: Could not write the statement 'CREATE STREAM IF NOT EXISTS ABC WITH (kafka_topic='ext_sink_connect_topic', value_format='AVRO', partitions=12);' into the command topic.
Caused by: Timeout while waiting for command topic consumer to process command
```

How can I resolve the error or any workaround would be helpful.